# AngularJS directive not working

Tags: angularjs, directive, plunker

I have a plunker for this issue at http://plnkr.co/edit/yJNrpATGWY7iUeVcx6lx?p=preview

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ItemEnum">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.0.0" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.0-rc3-nonmin" data-semver="1.2.0-rc3-nonmin" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="EnumCtrl">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                <a ng-href="" di-enum-items di-item-class="link_active">
                   <span> {{item.name}} ({{item.count}}) </span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**script.js**:

```
angular.module('ItemEnum', [])
.controller('EnumCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
      {name: 'cars',count: 10},
      {name: 'bikes',count: 20}
    ];
  })
  .directive('diEnumItems', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        diItemClass: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

          $(element).bind('click', function() {
              if ( $(element).hasClass(attrs.diItemClass) ) {
                  element.removeClass(attrs.diItemClass);
              } else {
                  element.addClass(attrs.diItemClass);
              }
          });

      }
    };
  });
```

**style.css**:

```
/* Styles go here */
.link_active {
    color: red;
}
```

Somehow the angular directive is screwing up the link enumeration.  What am I doing wrong?  Please note that I'm not looking for an answer that tells me that there is a more simple way of doing this.  I know I can just create a directive that simply acts on the css class alone -- and besides the css class operations the directive performs is working fine here.  This directive is more extensive and does some other stuff.  However, the plunker shows the basic problem I'm having.  I have read some other SO posts about directives as well as have read the Angular Directive guide but can't seem to get past this basic issue.

Comment: The title on this question is abysmal

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new scope on your directive that's screwing up the ng-href render. I don't really see any reason why you need a scope in this situation, since you're using attrs anyway, so I removed it. Works now.

http://plnkr.co/edit/6ocoBa9yTQWMeL95O5Yw?p=preview

Comment: Hi Mike, ok, yes, I could do that before and worked fine.  I've updated the plunker -- see http://plnkr.co/edit/yJNrpATGWY7iUeVcx6lx?p=preview -- to add more complexity closer to what I need.  Basically, when an item is activated/deactivated I need the directive to call a function in the outer controller that would refresh data in the whole page based on whether the filter was activated/deactivated. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if my last comment was clear but this is still an issue for me.  The plunker in the last comment has more details on the issue I'm facing where the directive's scope seems to screw up my ng-repeat enumeration.

Comment: @user2961845 Understood, I'm just at work ;) I think I see your problem and will play with it tonight.

Comment: Mike, not sure it is the best way, I got it to work in my code by using the transclude option.  I will try got get the plunker updated with the option.